# How to use @uses in phpDocumentor 2 for functions

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc

phpDocumentor [manual says](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/tags/uses.html) that you can add a `@uses` attribute to a docblock to reference used function and generate there a used_by attribute.
As I write mostly procedural php-code I like to reference my functions with the `@uses` tag

I tried it like this and I get no warnings or errors, but it generates not really a link, and no used_by link. The only thing I get is the attribute with a text of the function name Where is my mistake?

```
/**
 * Searches for string in given field and returns Array of objects
 * @param $strSearch    string to be searched for in database
 * @return array
 * @uses function mysqlConnect
 */
function blablablub($strSearch){ /*here goes the code...*/ }
```

Comment: Try removing the word function?

Comment: Tbh, I wouldn't put that into the DocBlock. The developer doesn't need to know that implementation detail at this position and it only puts maintenance overhead on you when you change the implementation. Also, if that function requires a mysql connection resource, make that an argument to the function.

Comment: removing 'function' results in something like '\global\functionName'

Comment: Looks like maybe it should be @uses functionname() comment - see http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.uses.pkg.html

Comment: it's the some with parantheses, just results in '\global\functionName()'

Comment: Isn't "\global\functionName()" what you want?  That function is in the global namespace, presumably, so the "\global" prefix on it just makes that knowledge explicit.  Is it not still correctly providing a hyperlink to the doc page for functionName()?

Comment: it's not providing a hyperlink at all, just text. Could it be some config thing?

Comment: Looks like this is an open bug -- https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/920

Answer (score 0):

as [manual says](https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.uses.pkg.html)  *The @uses tag may be used to document any element (global variable, include, page, class, function, define, method, variable)*

*@uses is very similar to @see, see the documentation for @see for details on format and structure. The @uses tag differs from @see in two ways. @see is a one-way link, meaning the documentation containing a @see tag contains a link to other documentation. The @uses tag automatically creates a virtual @usedby tag in the other documentation that links to the documentation containing the @uses tag. In other words, it is exactly like @see, except a return link is added automatically.*

```
  /**
 * Searches for string in given field and returns Array of objects
 * @param $strSearch    string to be searched for in database
 * @return array
 * @uses subclass sets a temporary variable
 * @uses subclass::$foo this is compared to TEST_CONST
 * @uses TEST_CONST compared to subclass::$foo, we
 * @uses some_function
 */
  function blablablub($strSearch){ /*here goes the code...*/ }
```